# listView and cursoradapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I'm working on my final project and I am faced with a problem. I want to pass data from my database (DatabaseBon) to a listview. Can anybody help me out?

My Activity looks like:

```
      public class BlackNumbersBlockDb extends Activity {
        String TAG;
       @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.blocknumbersdb);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Button imBT= (Button)findViewById(R.id.importBL);
    DataBaseBON info= new DataBaseBON(this);
    info.open();
    Cursor cursor=info.getcursor();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    ContactCursorAdapter adapter = new ContactCursorAdapter(null, cursor);
    ListView contactLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewblDB);
    contactLV.setAdapter(adapter);
    info.close();
        imBT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i= new Intent ("android.intent.action.IMPORTM");
            startActivity(i);   
        }
    });
```

My cursoradapter looks like:

```
    **import vahid.engineer.com.DataBaseBON** ( is it c orrect??)
     .
     .
     .


    public class ContactCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter  {
  public ContactCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {  
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.blacklistDB1);
    name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseBON.N_NAME)));
    TextView phone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.blacklistDB2); 
    phone.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseBON.KEY_NUMBER)));}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv, parent, false);
    bindView(v, context, cursor);
    return v;
```

My LV XML file looks like

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/blacklistDB1"
          android:layout_width="33dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Large Text"
          />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blacklistDB2"
        android:layout_width="19dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        />
      </LinearLayout>
```

my blockornot XML file looks like

```
   <  LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >
  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/listviewblDB"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="499dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.72" >
    </ListView>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="129dp"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal|fill|top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/importBL"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Import"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteBL"
        android:layout_width="126dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
      </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <TextView
      android:id="@+id/blacklistDB1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
     <TextView
      android:id="@+id/blacklistDB2"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="626dp"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal|fill|top"
   android:orientation="horizontal" />
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="129dp"
      android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal|fill|top"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/importBT"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Import" android:textSize="30sp"/>
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/deleteBT"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
          android:text="Delete" android:textSize="30sp"/>
       </LinearLayout>
```

My error

```
      java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:171)
    at vahid.engineer.com.ContactCursorAdapter.newView(ContactCursorAdapter.java:40)
 at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:182)
     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
 at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```